# Compute the number of sequence permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I would like to compute the no. possible permutations for a sub-set of objects. Consider the set of objects:
$$
X = \{X_1,X_2,X_3,....,X_N\}
$$
Question: What is the number of ways that I can pick a sub-sequence from $X$ of length $M \leq N$, such that:

1. Each object, $X_i$, may only appear once in the sub-sequence
2. Order matters, i.e. $S_1 = \{X_1, X_2, X_3\}$ is not the same as $S_2 = \{X_2, X_1, X_3\}$ - i.e. these two examples count as 2
3. Rotational symmetry, i.e. $S_1 = \{X_1, X_2, X_3\}$ is the same as $S_2 = \{X_2, X_3, X_1\}$ - i.e. these two examples count as 1. The reason for this is that $S_2$ appears as a sub-sequence of $S_1$ if $S_1$ is repeated $\{X_1, \mathbf{X_2, X_3\} \{X_1}, X_2, X_3\}$.

I have been able to come up with a formula for the problem accounting for 1) and 2). The number of combinations is the ways to choose M items from N items set. Without repetition and with order, the formula is: $\frac{N!}{(N-M)!}$. However, I do not know how to extend the formula to account for 3).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have been able to come up with a formula for the problem accounting for 1) and 2). The number of combinations is the ways to choose M items from N items set. Without repetition and with order, the formula is: N!/(N-M)!. However, I do not know how to extend the formula to account for 3).

Comment: There are $M$ ways to rotate a set so you get $N!/(N-M)!/M$

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A002104

Comment: @Empy2  You should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are $M$ ways to rotate a set, so you get $$\frac{N!}{M(N-M)!}$$
The total, for $M=1$ to $N$, is in http://oeis.org/A002104

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try with the problem yourself, it's interesting! Here are some pointers

1. Each $n$-element set $S$ has $2^{\vert S\vert}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}$ subsets.
2. Each subset $S_k \subseteq S$ has $k!$ permutations.
3. **Rotation is tricky though**. Check [*Merry-go-rounds*](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/%7Exinweiyu/421.Q1.17w/421Q1Winter2017_L18_20170227.pdf) problem.

Comment: But wasn't rotation not just as computed in the answer above? why is it tricky

Comment: if $k$ is not prime, then some permutations would repeat, so you have to exclude them